# Post to a node drupal 7

Tags: php, rest, post, drupal-7, nodes

I am very new to drupal, and am trying to post data from a form to my druple install.

I have set up my Services module set up and have built a basic node

**My Node**

*sites/all/modules/custom/bd_profile/bd_profile.module*

**bd_profile.module**

```
<?php

function bd_profile_services_resources() {
    return array(
        'bd_profile' => array(                            // My new resource
            'create' => array(
                'callback' => '_bd_profile_create_node',
                'access callback' => '_bd_profile_create_access',
                'args' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'node',
                        'optional' => FALSE,
                        'source' => 'data',                         // Setting the source to 'data' in your args means that any data in the POST will be passed to the callback function
                        'description' => 'The node data to create',
                        'type' => 'array',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
}

/**
 * Access callback
 */
function _bd_profile_create_access() {
    return TRUE;
}

/**
 * Callback function that creates the node
 */
function _bd_profile_create_node($arg) {
    // Minimally there needs to be something submitted
    if($arg) {
        // Create the node
        $node = new stdClass();
        $node->type = 'bio';
        $node->title = $arg['name'];
        $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
        $node->uid = 0;
//      $node->uid = $user->uid;
//      $node->status = 1; //(1 or 0): published or not
//      $node->promote = 0; //(1 or 0): promoted to front page
//      $node->comment = 1; // 0 = comments disabled, 1 = read only, 2 = read/write
        node_object_prepare($node);

        // Create a map of predefined POST args to Drupal fields
        $map = array(
            'job_title' => 'field_title',
            'message' => 'body',
        );

        // Array to store both mapped and unmapped fields
        $node_fields = array();

        // What predefined args have been passed?
        $arr1 = array_intersect_key($arg, $map);
        // Build an array associating Drupal fieldnames to arg values
        foreach($arr1 as $key => $value) {
            $field = $map[$key];                    // Get the drupal field that matches the form field
            $node_fields[$field] = $value;
        }

        // What undefined (ie. unknown) args have been passed?
        $arr2 = array_diff_key($arg, $map);
        // Associate unknown arg values with the 'general info' field on our bio/profile pages
        foreach($arr2 as $key => $value) {
            if(isset($node_fields['field_general_info'])) {
                $node_fields['field_general_info'] .= $key . " | " . $value . "\n";
            } else {
                $node_fields['field_general_info'] = $key . " | " . $value . "\n";
            }
        }

        // Save all arg values as Drupal fields
        foreach($node_fields AS $key => $value) {
            $node->{$key}[$node->language][0]['value'] = $value;
        }

        // Save the node
        $node = node_submit($node);
        node_save($node);
    } else {
        // Error if no args were passed
        return services_error(t('No data submitted!'), 406, t('No data submitted!'));
    }
}
```

this is now active in my Services Resource as bd_profile and create checked

my path to endpoint: **bensapi**

And next I have a simple form that POST

**myform.html**

```
<form action="http://localhost/myapp/bensapi/node" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="50%">
<tr>
  <td>Your name:</td><td><input name="name" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Job title:</td><td><input name="job_title" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Age:</td><td><input name="age" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Hometown:</td><td><input name="hometown" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Hometown state:</td><td><input name="state" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Bio/message:</td><td><textarea name="message"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save">&nbsp;
  <input type="reset" value="Clear"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

finally my new content type is set up like so

[image]

Once I post I just get

```
<result>Node bd_profile could not be found</result>
```

I am new to drupal and do not know where I have gone wrong, any help to get this working would be good.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use services but for creating endpoint pages you can use hook_menu:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x

This should work:

```
function bd_profile_menu() {
    $items['add_node'] = array(
        'title' => 'Adding a node',
        'page callback' => '_bd_profile_create_node',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    );
}
```

.. where "add_node" is path of your end point. You can place other value if you like of course.